# "A control modification's name must be a control in the base form."

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I want to modify bankChequeTable form. I have added display method field to the overview field group in the table. This field has been shown in the form but I want to change the label. After changing, the compiler shows this error :

> "A control modification's name must be a control in the base form."

Actually, when I change each property of the custom fields located in the overview groups this error comes. for example when I change their visibility.

this the image of the error
[image]

I am using 2019 release wave 2 
Installed product version :Finance and Operations (10.0.5)
Installed platform version : Update29 (7.0.5372.35448)

what is this error? How can I modify the property of the fields which are editable?

Comment: On which version are you? I tried to reproduce this on a 10.0.10 PU 34 system and changed visibility of control `Grid_TransDate` to No, but the build completed successfully. I also tried adding the existing display method `displayRemittanceLocation` to the `Overview` table group and then changed the label of the resulting control in the grid, but again, no compiler error. Are you sure the display method is correctly implemented (maybe [edit] the code into your question)?

Comment: [Similar question](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/284454/a-control-modification-s-name-must-be-a-control-in-the-base-form/906664) in the community forum.

Comment: @FH-Inway similar question with no answer. I had been tried the last suggestion after that I asked question here.

Comment: As asked before by @FH-Inway, which version are you using? Moreover, maybe you should consider providing a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: @IlVic this is the version I am using : 2019 release wave 2
Installed product version : Finance and Operations (10.0.5)
Installed platform version : Update29 (7.0.5372.35448)

Comment: @FH-Inway did you add custom field? in your model? please change the visibility of the field which is custom

Comment: No, I have not. Refer to my first comment as to what I did and please [edit] more detailed repro steps to your question as well as the other information you have given in your comments. This will increase the chance for an answer. Also try to reproduce your issue on the latest version.

Comment: @FH-Inway I update my post

Comment: Thanks. I also added a string field to the table, added it to the field group and then set the resulting control in the form grid to be invisible. This compiled fine, however, I noticed that the field is still shown in the ui. I also noticed that the custom label of my test with the `displayRemittanceLocation` is not used. So there is something weird going on, but with different results between your version and mine. I recommend you try to reproduce on the current version and look in issue search for fixes. Otherwise you may have to contact Microsoft support.

Comment: @FH-Inway Thank you updating to the last version is not up to me the infrastructure administrators decide so sorry I can't update it.